# Google Drive: is it possible to restore the way how the service worked in the past, using the folder instead of virtual partition?

Tags: windows, sync, google-drive

I use Windows 10 X64 Pro and I pay the annual fee for the 2TB Google Drive service as a private.

Originally, Google Drive service worked using a simple folder on a local drive where put all the stuff you wanted to sync and for me everything was fine.

After, Google decided to change the way of managing its cloud-based storage and now the program creates a FAT32 virtual drive for managing the sync. The problem is that certain applications refuse to save its projects in a FAT32 drive and one of these is Audacity, a program that I use everyday for my job, due to the fact that a FAT32 drive cannot handle files larger that 4GB.

[image: Audacicy Error]

In this case I have to save my project on another location and then, after finishing work, I can save it on the virtual drive for sync but from my point of view it frustrates the practicality of a cloud-based storage system.

Another program that gives me problems is Premiere Pro.

My questions:

1. Is there a way for restore the previous way of functioning of this service, using a folder instead of a virtual partition for sync?
2. If this is a FAT32 partition, putting files larger than 4GB could be dangerous in the meaning that they could be saved corrupted?

Comment: The only solution I know is to use a third-party application to mount the location differently through WEBDAV.  I have a suspicion that the drive isn't actually FAT32 for a lot of reasons. Other than the fact you get that error message how did you determine it was FAT32? I don't have a system with Google Drive on it handy so i can't look myself.

Comment: @Ramhound
Hi, just checking for the volume properties: right click on in in Explorer and choosing "Properties": File System FAT32

Comment: I have a Drobo network drive that indicates it's NTFS except it's not actually NTFS since it's a Drobo.  I will look into this issue but I use alternatives to mount all my cloud based products with WebDav.

Comment: [DfD includes a caching mechanism and a side effect of that is the OS reports it as a FAT32 volume when in actual fact it's not.](https://support.google.com/a/thread/118079454/google-drive-file-stream-creates-a-drive-that-s-fat32-and-i-require-ntfs?hl=en).  THey eventually linked to [Use Google Drive for desktop](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10838124) which I assume will get what you want if you chance it from the current setting.

Comment: Now you might not like you have to do that, but as I expected, it's a virtual file system which is simply reported as FAT32.  Which is the reason your workaround works.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Drive for desktop, you can switch your preferences from streaming to mirroring. This will download the entire contents of your Google Drive to a folder on your local drive, and this can be an NTFS drive. Here's the instructions from the [docs](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10838124#zippy=%2Cswitch-from-streaming-to-mirroring):

> 1. Configure My Drive for streaming or mirroring
> 2. Open Drive for desktop.
> 3. Click Settings and then Preferences.
> 4. On the left, click Folders from Drive.
> 5. Under "My Drive syncing options," select Stream files or Mirror files.

I was running into the same issue you had after upgrading to Audacity 3.2.5 from a much older install, and I can confirm that changing the settings fixed the issue. I'm now able to save Audacity projects to Google Drive without any error messages.